# Duplicates suggested by mere mortals no longer included in Mjölnir-dupevote?

Tags: feature-request, bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Scenario:

- A question is asked that has multiple duplicates
- Some "mere mortal" (A) (i.e. a user not having a gold tag badge for any of the tags on the question) finds one duplicate question URL (1) and votes to close with that question as duplicate suggestion
- A Mjölnir-holder (B) (i.e. a user having a gold tag badge for any of the tags on the question) comes along with *another* duplicate question URL (2) and votes to close the question as duplicate of that question

Now if memory serves me right, what *used* to happen up till a couple of days or weeks ago, the question would be closed, and in the close-banner, both user A and B were mentioned, and questions 1 and 2 were linked to.

This might have to do with user A having fewer than 3000 reputation, not giving them close-vote-rights, but still.

So I'm not certain whether this should be a bugreport (because I believe it used to work as described) or a feature request (because I *want* it to work as as described), so I'll tag both and just list my expectations:

- When a question is closed as a duplicate by the last vote (either binding through Mjölnir or not), list, in the close-banner, *all* proposed duplicates by close-flaggers and close-voters alike.

---

Related reading material:

- Übermeta: [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) (the introduction of Mjölnir / [dupehammer](/questions/tagged/dupehammer))
- Übermeta: [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) (the introduction of multiple, editable duplicate question links)

Comment: Unless this has changed today, I also remember seeing the duplicate suggested added to my link.

Comment: Were user A mention even when they didn't have 3k rep and only _flagged_ the question? Also, was the link added when a user voted to close the question and not if it only got flagged? Or in both cases?

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure. I don't think flaggers (<3K rep) are mentioned in the close banner, but I think their suggested duplicates were shown.

Comment: As far as I remember that was the case, yes. If it is different now (their link is not shown anymore), then this behaviour is new.

Comment: Just to confirm my recollection of the behavior that used to exist: Dup flaggers always left a "possible duplicate..." auto comment.  And in the close dialog it showed what they voted for.  But their votes were never counted nor was their name shown in the banner.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's correct, as far as I remember. But if I recall correctly, duplicates mentioned by flaggers also ended up in the duplicate-close-banner.

Comment: Mere mortals? I beg your pardon! I've not died for many days in a row. By induction I can conclude that if I've not died so far, I won't die in the future. Therefore, I must be immortal.

Comment: @vlaz I'd also prefer the term *baldurs* ... :)

Comment: @JonasWilms nice mythology reference :D